# How to add a timeout or pause in a batch file to open firefox tabs each X seconds

Tags: batch-file, firefox, tabs, timeout, pause

Hello im having a hard time to make a batch file to open new firefox tab windows to several links. My objective its firefox open several links 1 by 1 or in a group of 5 for example since its a big list, with a pause to give me time to close the older tabs before making whole system go very slow.

I have try this:

`@echo off
start firefox.exe --new-window www.cnn.com/
timeout /t 60
start firefox.exe www.bbc.uk
timeout /t 15
start firefox.exe www.google.com
timeout /t 15
start firefox.exe www.yahoo.com
timeout /t 15
close firefox.exe
exit`

This gives me 2 problems, he opens a new firefox window instead of using the one already in use but more serious and problematic, he doesn't open a new tab to each link. Instead he opens a new browner to each link what makes my system go slow very fast.
How i fix this 2 problems?

Comment: So open them in groups.  `start firefox www.cnn.com www.google.com www.bbc.uk`

Comment: that opens in groups but the next group he opens a new browser instead of new tab

Comment: Did you try the `-new-tab` option?